# Unexepected result for 'getopt' function

Tags: python, getopt

I have the following function:

```
def getOptions(logfile):
    try:
        options, arguments = getopt.getopt(programArguments[1:], 'nt:v:L:d:', ['help'])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print("\nERROR: Invalid Option")
        usage()
        exit()
```

where `programArguments = sys.argv`.

The `getopt` function is always returning nothing into `options` and returns a copy of `programArguments[1:]` into `arguments`. Where am I going wrong with `getopt`?

**EDIT**

See my answer below where I realised my mistake.

Comment: Please show an example of this, with appropriate `sys.argv` input.

Comment: Also consider using argparse instead.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem: `getopt.getopt(['-n', '-v2'], 'nt:v:L:d:', ['help'])` returns `([('-n', ''), ('-v', '2')], [])`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dashes before each argument? (e.g. `python program.py -n 1`)? If you were to run it like `python program.py n 1` it would go into arguments.

You should only see values in `arguments` if you are passing values that are not assigned to a value. So for this call I get:

```
> python test_getopt.py --treatment=1

options: [('--treatment', '1')] arguments: []
```

You would then loop through the (key, value) pairs of options.

On the other hand, if I pass an additional value that is not associated with a key it will be inserted into the arguments list. For example:

```
> python test_getopt.py --treatment=1 temp.txt

options: [('--treatment', '1')] arguments: ['temp.txt']
```

See the [getopt documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) for more thorough documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that because my program takes a file as `argv[1]`, `getopt` was exiting once it found that `argv[1]` was not a valid option. Changing to `programArguments[2:]` solved the problem.